# How I can restore merged deleted branches from merged PR's in github upon rollback so I can manually re-merge them?

Tags: git, github

In my project I

Once I rollback changes to `master` branch to a specific tag I follow the following procedure:

1. I make a branch `before_rollback` that gets the changes from master:

   ```
    git checkout master
    # I'll need to use the before_rollback branch to make a diff for branches to re-merge
    git checkout -b before_rollback
    git checkout master
   ```
2. Then I revert to the tag I want to and forcefully push it:

   ```
      git reset --hard ^tag_to_revert^
      git push origin --force master
   ```

But `before_rollback` branch also contains some other changed comming from closed PR's with deleted branches from github. What I want to do is to re-open the branches and manually get the diff of the branched that need re-merge so I can re-merge them back.

In other words I want to somehow get a diff of the merged branches between `master` and `before_rollback` and re-open them, regardless if they have been deleted or not.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is more than one way, and you'll need to decide on some very specific, very picky little items before you can choose which way to go. Some details depend on *how* you did the merges. The good news is that since you're using GitHub, and GitHub save *everything forever*, you can get back exactly what you did last time by just going through the closed PRs to discover (and then recover) specific hash IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible alternative workflow for this:

1. Don't rewind `main`
2. Starting from the latest, for all bad PRs create revere commits and merge these changes to main.
3. Using a feature branch (or branches),

   - for each bad PR that was reverted,
   - starting from the oldest one,
   - create a reverse of the reverse (i.e. the original change)
   - and merge these to `main`,
   - modifying each merge of to you liking.

No `--force` anywhere.

Comment: Ok this is a better alternative ;). I am keeping this.